# Extracting csv files from multiple zipped files in python

Tags: python, csv

I have written a script which extracts text from multiple csv's. Can someone help me embed the script in this which can read csv data from different zipped files and create multiple csv's(one for each ziped file) at a location.
For example-- If i have 10 csv's in zipped folder z1 and 5 in zipped folder z2. I want to extract files from each zipped file and get the extracted files at one location. In this case it would be z1.csv(with concatenated data from 10 csv's) and z2.csv(with concatenated data from 5 csv's).
I am using the following script,

```
allfiles=glob.glob(os.path.join(input_fldr,"*.csv"))
a=[]
b=[]
for file_ in allfiles:
    dirname, filename=os.path.split(file_)
    f=open(file_,'r',encoding='UTF-8')
    lines=f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('Hello'):
        a.append(filename)
        b.append(line)
df_a=pd.DataFrame(a,columns=list("A")
df_b=pd.DataFrame(b,columns=list("B")
df=pd.concat([df_a,df_b],axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you provide some example of the data? Also, your current program seems **really unidiomatic**. Have you looked at the Pandas docs (do you want a Pandas solution?) ?

Comment: Could you also provide some explanation of your current code?

Answer (score 1):

### The Code

The code I came to, that does roughly what I believe you are wanting to happen is this (all the files you need for this example are [available here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KXWI11aGKjKFzrYhWB3_J4_IsakK2_bz)):

```py
import zipfile
import pandas as pd

virtual_csvs = []

with zipfile.ZipFile("test3.zip", "r") as f:
    for name in f.namelist():
        if name.endswith(".csv"):
            data = f.open(name)
            virtual_csvs.append(pd.read_csv(data, header=None))

pd.concat(virtual_csvs, axis=1).to_csv('test4.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

### Code Breakdown

```py
virtual_csvs = []
```

We start by creating an array that will store all of the panda DataFrames, much like your array `[df_a, df_b]`

```py
with zipfile.ZipFile("test3.zip", "r") as f:
```

This will load the zipfile, "test3.zip" - replace with your zipfile name, in read mode into the variable `f`

```py
for name in f.namelist():
```

This iterates over every file name in the zipfile, and loads that to the variable: `name`

```py
if name.endswith(".csv"):
```

This line is rather self-explanatory - if the file has an extension of `.csv`, run the following code.

```
data = f.open(name)
```

The `f.open(name)` command opens the file (`name`) - the equivalent would be `open(name, 'r') as data`

```py
virtual_csvs.append(pd.read_csv(data, header=None))
```

`pd.read_csv(data, header=None)` loads that file into a panda dataframe (header=None means no column headers so the data is loaded into a dataframe)

`virtual_csvs.append` loads the dataframe into the virtual_csvs list

The final line of this code:

```py
pd.concat(virtual_csvs, axis=1).to_csv('output.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

concatenates all of the csv files into one larger file ('output.csv').
`pd.concat(virtual_csvs, axis=1)` means to join all the csv files (DataFrame) in virtual_csvs by column (this returns a `pd.DataFrame`)

`to_csv('output.csv', header=False, index=False)` means to convert the given DataFrame to a csv file, named 'output.csv'.

`header=False` means to remove header names for each column

`index=False` disables row numbers from the DataFrames

Comment: Why the use of `StringIO`? Is using `pandas.read_csv()` directly not possible?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, you make a good point, I just re-read the ZipFile documentation and you are right there is a `zipfile.open` command. Thanks for the pointer, I'll append the code

Comment: Amusingly enough I wasn’t thinking about `zipfile.open`, I had misunderstood your code and just reread the docs myself lol

Comment: @AlexanderCécile the new code seems to do the job well enough, would be interesting if there was anything else that could be changed to improve performance.